# Running java jar outside eclipse requiring files in bin dir

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing using eclipse and I'm using an API that requires files to be in the /bin directory (which path does that mean in java I don't know). I exported my app as a jar and put the required files in the same directory as the jar file, but when I run the app using Terminal, the app is not able to locate the files. I'm unable to understand this paths issue.

I'm running the app with this command:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

I also changed the terminal directory into the directory that contains the jar file and I tried with:

```
java -cp . -jar app.jar
```

That didn't work.

Edit:
The error is that the application is not able to locate the required files. In Eclipse I had to put the files in the /bin dir in order for the API to locate them.

Here's the full exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: failed to find resource /cmu/arktweetnlp/50mpaths2
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.util.BasicFileIO.getResourceReader(BasicFileIO.java:233)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.impl.features.WordClusterPaths.<init>(WordClusterPaths.java:29)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.impl.features.FeatureExtractor.initializeFeatureExtractors(FeatureExtractor.java:146)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.impl.features.FeatureExtractor.<init>(FeatureExtractor.java:30)
    at cmu.arktweetnlp.Tagger.loadModel(Tagger.java:39)
    at com.POSTest.main(POSTest.java:22)
```

Terminal content:

```
MacBook-Pro:ArabicTwitterEye ma$ ls
CSVArabicTwitterEye.jar log         resources
cmu         profiles        tweets.csv
MacBook-Pro:ArabicTwitterEye ma$
```

Here's the simple java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tagger tagger = new Tagger();
        String modelFilename = "model.20120919";

        System.out.println( "Loading model ..." );
        try {
            tagger.loadModel(modelFilename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println( "Done loading model." );
    }
```

Here's the source code from the API:

```
public class WordClusterPaths implements FeatureExtractorInterface {

    /** TODO this should be moved into config somehow **/
    public static String clusterResourceName = "/cmu/arktweetnlp/50mpaths2";

    public static HashMap<String,String> wordToPath;

    public WordClusterPaths() throws IOException {
//      log.info("Loading clusters");

        //read in paths file
        BufferedReader bReader = BasicFileIO.getResourceReader(clusterResourceName);
        String[] splitline = new String[3];
        String line=BasicFileIO.getLine(bReader);
        wordToPath = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
        while(line != null){
            splitline = line.split("\\t");
            wordToPath.put(splitline[1], splitline[0]);
            line = BasicFileIO.getLine(bReader);
        }           
//      log.info("Finished loading clusters");
    }
```

Also check this:

```
public static BufferedReader getResourceReader(String resourceName) throws IOException {
        assert resourceName.startsWith("/") : "Absolute path needed for resource";

        InputStream stream = BasicFileIO.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        if (stream == null) throw new IOException("failed to find resource " + resourceName);
        //read in paths file
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        return bReader;
    }
```

Comment: and what is the error message, what is there that its not finding

Comment: Please show us more information. We can help you only as much as you help us.

Comment: What's inside `MANIFEST.MF` of your exported jar? Check `Class-Path` entry.

Comment: I edited the post to include more info

Comment: What do you mean "the app is not able to locate the files"? What files? Are these other files jar files from other APIs you may be using? Are you getting class not found errors? Can you post the error?

Comment: If you explicitly copied files into /bin in Eclipse (you should pretty-much never do that, BTW), you would also need them copied into your runtime folder (in your second example, the same folder with your .jar file).

Comment: **bin** is where Eclipse puts your classes (byte code). Have you tried putting your files in the same directory as your "*executable*"?

Comment: @PM77-1 my executable is a jar. I put the files in the same dir as the jar

Comment: Cut and paste the entire terminal window. Also show us the contents of the directories. (dir or ls)

Comment: Your `Exception` shows an **absolute** path where it tried to locate the file.  Is it hard-coded in your source code?

Comment: @PM77-1 That is correct, I checked the source code of the API and it says it uses absolute paths. Now I'm confused on how to solve the problem. Yes it's hard coded in the API code

Comment: @user1676075 that didn't work

Comment: I edited the post to include the source code of the API

Comment: Can you please let us know the API library you are using.From the source it seems it has some major bugs. " /** TODO this should be moved into config somehow **/ "???

Comment: @Algorithmist https://github.com/brendano/ark-tweet-nlp/

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your project in Eclipse. Then New -> Source Folder.
2. Name the source folder anything. e.g. cmu_src.
3. Copy or drag the entire cmu directory in cmu_src. Then make the jar.

Eclipse usually don't put the resource/assets directories when you create a jar.